# Как при выводе проверять все записи а не последнюю

Tags: php, sql

Выводит только последнее из базы, точнее проверка по последней строке в базе идет, а не по всем.

```
$test = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($tipe_b)) {
$test = $row['time'];
$day_b = $row['day'];
$month_b = $row['month'];
}
foreach ($proverka as $hhmm) { 
    $class = "";
if ($_GET['day'] == date('j') AND date('H:i') > $timss OR $_GET['month'] < date('m')) {
$class_l_a = "class='tables_l_not-active'";
} elseif ($test == $hhmm) {
$class_l_a = "class='tables_l_not-active'";
}
 else {
    $class_l_a = 'class="timb tables_l"';
}

echo $hhmm ;
}
```

Comment: @bajex, Задавайте вопросы в виде вопросов, а не комментариев к ответам.

Answer (score 1):

Вам необходимо производить вашу проверку внутри цикла (while)

```
$test = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($tipe_b)) {
    $test = $row['time'];
    $day_b = $row['day'];
    $month_b = $row['month'];
    foreach ($proverka as $hhmm) {
        $class = "";
        if ($_GET['day'] == date('j') AND date('H:i') > $timss OR $_GET['month'] < date('m')) {
            $class_l_a = "class='tables_l_not-active'";
        } elseif ($test == $hhmm) {
            $class_l_a = "class='tables_l_not-active'";
        } else {
            $class_l_a = 'class="timb tables_l"';
        }

        echo $hhmm;
    }
}
```